# Custom built opencv 4..7.0 python import problem

Tags: python, opencv, python-import

I built opencv 4.7.0 from source

I have a folder `cv2` with `cv2.so` in it

If I call `import cv2` within the folder -- all ok

If I call from without `from cv2 import cv2` or similar stuff, nothing will work with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Bindings generation error. Submodule name should always start with a parent module name. Parent name: cv2.cv2. Submodule name: cv2
```

Everything worked with opencv 4.5.5

I've seen similar problems with opencv-python: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/676

Does anyone knows how to solve this import issue?

Comment: do you use pycharm? why do you expect a wrong import statement to not throw an error? -- crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/custom-built-opencv-4-7-0-python-import-problem/11469

Comment: no, I use python prompt in linux terminal. `import foo from foo` is proper python way of importing if it corresponds to file/folder structure of your module